# Mockito spy referenced to wrong object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, mockito

I have problem with Mockito mocking library

My Junit4 test class with 2 test suites.

test one:

```
@Test
public void test1()
{
   Class class = new Class();
   Class classSpy = Mockito.spy(class);
   Mockito.when( classSpy.getExpectedValue()).thenReturn("expected_one");
}
```

and second test:

```
@Test
public void test2()
{
    Class class = new Class();
    Class classSpy = Mockito.spy(class);
    Mockito.when( classSpy.getExpectedValue()).thenReturn("expected_two");
}
```

and I have testable class:

```
public class TestableClass
{
    x = class.getExpectedValue();
    //some code
}
```

And the problem is:

1 - I run test class with `test1()` and `test2()`
    At first is running `test1()`
    debugger indicate the `x = "expected_one"`
    all is ok - this is expected behavior

2 - test2 is running
    I put breakpoint in my testable class at line with x.. 
    and `x = "expected_one"`

I seems Mockito uses the same reference to spying object (`classSpy`) in both test.!!

thanks in advance for help

ps: i use mockito 1.9.0 and jre 6.0.370.6

ps: I have normal SetUp method:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){

    testableClass = new TestableClass();
}
```

ps3: full test suite:

```
package xxx;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import xxx.testdata.JUnitConstants;
import xxx.testdata.JUnitUtils;
import xxx.testdata.MockNode;


@SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )
public class MONodeModifierTest
{

    private MONodeModifier moNodeModifier;
    private Document doc;
    static File file;



    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        doc = JUnitUtils.CreateXMLDocumentFromFile(file);
        moNodeModifier = new MONodeModifier(doc);
    }


    @Test
    public void createNodeTest(){

        Node inputMoNode = new MockNode();

        boolean nodeisCreated = moNodeModifier.createMONode( inputMoNode, doc );
        Assert.assertTrue(nodeisCreated);
    }

    @Test
    public void removeNodeTest(){

        final Node inputMoNode = new MockNode();
        NodeList nodeList = new NodeList(){

            @Override
            public Node item( int index )
            {
                return inputMoNode;
            }

            @Override
            public int getLength()
            {
                return 1;
            }};

        boolean nodeisRemoved = moNodeModifier.removeMONode( inputMoNode,nodeList );
        Assert.assertTrue(nodeisRemoved);
    }

    @Test
    public void updateMONodeWithPname(){

        Node node = new MockNode();
        NodeList nodeListMock = Mockito.mock( NodeList.class );
        Node nodeSpy = Mockito.spy(node);
        Mockito.when( nodeSpy.getChildNodes()).thenReturn( nodeListMock);
        Mockito.when( nodeSpy.getNodeName()).thenReturn( "p");

        Mockito.when( nodeListMock.getLength()).thenReturn( 1);
        Mockito.when( nodeListMock.item(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn( nodeSpy);

        boolean nodeisUpdated = moNodeModifier.updateMONode( nodeSpy, nodeListMock );
        Assert.assertTrue(nodeisUpdated);

        Mockito.verify( nodeSpy).setTextContent(Mockito.anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void updateMONodeWithNonEmptyListName(){

        Node node = new MockNode();
        NodeList nodeListMock = Mockito.mock( NodeList.class );
        Node nodeSpy = Mockito.spy(node);
        Mockito.when( nodeSpy.getChildNodes()).thenReturn( nodeListMock);
        Mockito.when( nodeSpy.getNodeName()).thenReturn( "list");

        Mockito.when( nodeListMock.getLength()).thenReturn( 1).thenReturn( 1);
        Mockito.when( nodeListMock.item(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn( nodeSpy);


        boolean nodeisUpdated = moNodeModifier.updateMONode( nodeSpy, nodeListMock );
        Assert.assertTrue(nodeisUpdated);

        Mockito.verify( nodeSpy).replaceChild(Mockito.any(Node.class),Mockito.any(Node.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void updateNonExistMONodeType(){

        Node node = new MockNode();
        Node nodeSpy = Mockito.spy(node);

        NodeList nodeListMock = Mockito.mock( NodeList.class );

        Mockito.when( nodeSpy.getChildNodes()).thenReturn( nodeListMock);
        Mockito.when( nodeSpy.getNodeName()).thenReturn( "p");
        Mockito.when( nodeSpy.getNodeType()).thenReturn( (short) 1).thenReturn( (short) 1).thenReturn( (short) 1).thenReturn( (short) 2);

        Mockito.when( nodeListMock.getLength()).thenReturn( 1);
        Mockito.when( nodeListMock.item(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn( nodeSpy);


        boolean nodeisCreated = moNodeModifier.updateMONode( nodeSpy, nodeListMock );
        Assert.assertTrue(nodeisCreated);

        Mockito.verify( nodeSpy).appendChild(Mockito.any(Node.class));

    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void prepareFileBeforeTests() throws IOException
    {
        file = JUnitUtils.copyFile(
            new File( "xx.xml" ), new File( "testfile.xml" ));
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void deleteFileAfterTests()
    {
        JUnitUtils.deleteFile( new File(
            "testfile.xml" ) );
    }

}
```

and the spying class:

```
package xxx.testdata;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo;
import org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler;



    public class MockNode implements Node,Element,Attr
    {


        @Override
        public NodeList getChildNodes()
        {
            return new NodeList(){

                @Override
                public int getLength()
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                @Override
                public Node item( int index )
                {
                    return new MockNode();
                }};
        }

        @Override
        public String getNodeName()
        {
            return "name";
        }

        @Override
        public short getNodeType()
        {   
            return 1;
        }


    }
```

and updateMONode() method:

```
boolean updateMONode( Node inputMoNode, NodeList targetNodeList )
{
    String inputMoDn = Utils.getAttrValue( inputMoNode, "distName" );
    for( int i = 0; i < targetNodeList.getLength(); i++ )
    {
        Node targetMoNode = targetNodeList.item( i );
        String targetMoDn = Utils.getAttrValue( targetMoNode, "distName" );
        if( (targetMoNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) &&
            (inputMoNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) )
        { 
            if( Utils.compareDns( targetMoDn, inputMoDn ) )
            {
                NodeList parameters = inputMoNode.getChildNodes();
                boolean isParameterChanged = false;
                boolean isChanged = false;
                for( int j = 0; j < parameters.getLength(); j++ )
                {
                    if( (parameters.item( j ).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) )
                        isChanged =
                            updateParamNode(
                                parameters.item( j ), targetMoNode,
                                inputMoDn );
                    if( isChanged )
                    {
                        isParameterChanged = isChanged;
                        isUpdatedParameterNode = false;
                    }
                }
                if( isParameterChanged )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use this declaration : Class class = new ClassMock();?

Comment: Do you override `setUp()` to reset all variables before new test?

Comment: @loan: sorry for the Class name it can provide to misunderstand. I changed it

Comment: @qiGuar - Yes i have '@BeforeTest' nad '@BeforeClass' methods in my test. But 'i think' it not related to described problem

Comment: Actually it matters. Each test should be run independently from each other and test1 should cause no affect to test 2. I assume, that your variable doesn't initializes properly after test1. If you could add how you Mock everything, it might help.

Comment: @qiGuar i use set up to initialize another object, nothing more. I assume the normal Java behavior is: when i create Pointer and link to them new Object instance(Class class = new Class(); and Class classSpy = Mockito.spy(class);) the Pointer should point to my new Object. not any another - as we can see in my  case.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to do the following ` Mockito.when( nodeListMock.getLength()).thenReturn( 1).thenReturn( 1);` listing `thenReturn(1)` once will cause it to return 1 for all calls.

Comment: FYI, the infinite loop in the spys / mocks is a bit worrysome (the fact that spy returns list for children and list returns spy).

Comment: @john b thats true. In this case there shouldnt be chaining invocation. Propably i would to get another value. my mistake. what You mean exactly, infiinite loops is spys/mock is worrysome? where i have infinite loops?

Comment: You spy returns the list when calling `getChildren` then the list returns the spy on call to `item`. So this results in the spy being a child of itself.

Comment: but the method public NodeList getChildNodes() is not spying and 'item' method inside it do not return Mockito.spy object, but the real MockNode.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the situation is that you have not injected the newly created spy into the `TestableClass`. You create the spy uniquely in each test, do you also assign the newly created spy into the test class's `class` field?

Comment: In every test suite i injected properly a new created mock, like this: testableClass.testableMethod( classSpy );. This is very strange. I run the test one more time. (without project clean and rebuild) and issue was missed. New mock object are properly used. So the issue is not 100% reproducible. But for sure it exists. Before that i thought it rather a bug inside mockito reflection code, or something like that. Now i have no idea.

Comment: Not a bug in Mockito. I suggest you post more code so that we might be able to give better input. Post entire test, the setter and entire method under test.

Comment: If it is not consistent, are you attempting to run the tests in a multi-threaded env? Is the class multi-threaded?

Comment: i put the whole test class. The problem is with getNodeType() and getNodeName() methods. Both of them returned values from Spy object used in previous runned Junit4 @Test. I don't know Junit4 is multithreaded, i suppose test suites are running in random order

Comment: i published it, but i You looking for multithreaded code You will be disapointed ;)